# Output/path/structure strategy for Gulp builds of full-stack apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack, mean-stack

I am setting up my own "seed" of Mongo+Angular+Node+Node in part because I want to learn more of the particulars I've glossed over and in part because I want more control and structure than the `yo` generators provide.

I have several questions but at the root of all of them is a lack of understanding about the deployment/maintenance of a full-stack (MEAN) JS application. For brevity, I'll call it an FS JS app.

By understanding the answers to a few basic questions I can design my seed with more confidence and in the spirit I intend.

#### Is an FS JS app started the same way in production as it is in development, ie by calling `node`?

The answer is yes, I think, but I just wanted to make sure.

#### How do pros deploy FS JS apps? What do the tangible deployment files look like? Is installation still via `npm install`?

Here is where I first run into trouble. I've seen many seeds that build server code to a `/dist/` subdirectory. This makes me think that either we are supposed to bundle everything we need into `dist` and zip it, or we are supposed to install with `npm` and run the server from the `dist` rather than the `source` directory - ie zip/git the entire `/` where the `package.json` is, copy it to the destination, clone/unzip, and then `npm install` it there.

#### Is it desirable/easy/common to try to transform the server file structure such that the source files are combined into one file?

I know that for the client files, it makes sense to bundle them together to save network overhead. So at least we may bundle all the client files and use modules to imitate files, and an entire file structure may become just `app.js`. Even the dependencies can be merged into a single file and often are with a `Gulp` task.

But for server, is this something I should try to do? If so, any tips?

#### Is it best practice to minify and/or uglify server files?

Ditto

#### What is the order of operations wrt server source transformations so that paths are not an issue as a result?

For `client` stuff I usually do something like this:

1. Use `webpack` with `babel` to transpile `es6` to `es5` into a single `.js` file in a temporary folder
2. Do stuff to the `js` file in the temporary folder, like minify it or uglify it, one at a time of course.
3. Pipe from tmp to real folder, and then clean up

### This is what I have in mind

```
- bower_components
- node_modules
- source
  - client
  - common
    - infrastructure
      - utility
        ... ie tree-merger.js ...
  - configuration
    - client
    - server
      - express
        - default.json
        - production.environment.json
    - default.json
    - development.environment.json
    - production.environment.json
  - server
- task
  - gulp
    - ...
    - client-webpack.js
    - ...
    - server-build.js
    - ...
- target
  - .tmp (temp)
  - development
    - source
      (carbon copy of source, except injections are done where needed and SCSS is built into CSS. Reads from bower_components as needed.)
  - test
    - ???
  - production
    - bin
      - client
        - app.js
        - app.css
        image
      - server
        ???
```

Answer (score 1):

**Is an FS JS app started the same way in production as it is in development, ie by calling node?**

Yes. However, in production, you should write some init script which monitors your `node` instance and re-runs it, if it crashes for some reason

**How do pros deploy FS JS apps? What do the tangible deployment files look like? Is installation still via npm install?**

`npm install` is quite fine, however, remember that you definitely should gnerate `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file (by running `npm shrinkwrap`). Besides this, you can deploy with any node-agnostic tool you like (even simple shell script is surprisingly OK for this. When my project grows bigger, I replace it with `Python` script).

I don't see a reason for minifying / babelifying server-side code. You can easily run the sources 'as they are', babelifying them at require time (`babel-register` can be used for this). Also, es6 `import`s are transformed to node's standard `resolve`s, so there's no need to 'inline' dependencies. Maybe the minifying buys you some speed (theoretically, it should be really minimal), but it's definitely not worth it, unless you're app is facebook-like big; I think, this answers the rest of the questions.